# InstallerJS access to the pkg file name

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

My PKG file name is unique per user download. Does the JS within the Distribution.xml file have access to the pkg file name or full file path?

I know the pre and post install scripts have access to the following environment variables

```
$0 - Script path
$1 - Package path //path including file name
$2 - Target location
$3 - Target volume
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?